# python pandas bar plot another column text

Tags: python, pandas

```
     max min  mincount maxcount
0     12  10     1        6
1     21  14     1        6
2     34  19     1        6
3      6  20     1        4
4      8  22     1        4
5     41  23     1        4
```

this is pandas DataFrame.
so I want like this image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPqaB.jpg)

text label is very important.

here my code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'maxcount': max_count, 'mincount': min_count, 'max': max, 'min': min})
ax = df[['maxcount', 'mincount']].plot(kind='bar')
```

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns

#create your dataframe
d= {'max':[12,21,34,6,8,41],'min':[10,14,19,20,22,23],
'mincount':[1,1,1,1,1,1],'maxcount':[6,6,6,4,4,4]}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
#create 2 dataframes counts and max_min (1 for plotting and 1 for text)
counts=pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['maxcount','mincount'])
max_min=pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['max','min'])

#plot the counts
ax=counts[counts.columns].plot(kind='bar',colormap='Paired',figsize= (12,4))

#using zip() and ax.annotate specify where (location by means of z) 
#and what (max_min or counts) you want to plot
for x,y,z in zip(max_min.iloc[:,0].values,counts.iloc[:,0].values, range(len(counts))):
    ax.annotate('%.d' % x, (z-0.2, counts.iloc[z,0]), va='bottom', ha='center', fontsize=10)
    ax.annotate("("'%.d' % y+")", (z-0.1, counts.iloc[z,0]), va='bottom', ha='center', fontsize=10)

for x,y,z in zip(max_min.iloc[:,1].values,counts.iloc[:,1].values, range(len(counts))):
    ax.annotate('%.d' % x, (z+0.1, counts.iloc[z,1]), va='bottom', ha='center', fontsize=10)
    ax.annotate("("'%.d' % y+")", (z+0.2, counts.iloc[z,1]), va='bottom', ha='center', fontsize=10)
```

This is the output:
[image]